# Tablet + web app with USB-connected devices, or a pipe dream?

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight, usb, tablet

I have a .NET WinForms app wherein the laptop is connected to both a scale and an GPS antenna via USB.  Is it crazy to think we could have this instead as a web app and on a tablet?  We're looking to make things thinner and smaller (this goes in a truck.. driver doesn't need bulk of keyboard either).

Obviously the tablet would have to have a USB port (some do, some don't).  But then for "stickiness" to USB devices, I'd have to have, what, a Silverlight control on an ASP.NET page?  More trouble than its worth?

Thanks for any thoughts/advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an ActiveX control or browser plugin to use the USB port (Silverlight might not be able to do what you need). Unfortunately these controls most probably will have to be installed on the machine manually (unless you want to lower security settings for the browser). You might be better off using ClickOnce with your WinForms application to simplify deployment of new versions and keep using your existing codebase.

If all you need is to read the GPS data, you should use HTML5 Geolocation API: [Demo](http://html5demos.com/geo) and [Specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have connected USB barcode scanners to iPads through the USB to 30-Pin adapter with great luck. The only trouble is there is a power limitation, if the device draws more than a couple hundred milliamps the iPad will shut of the power to the device. You might have trouble hooking up peripherals that are not acting like a keyboard or a camera though.